# The right way parse html to jQuery object

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to parse a html string to jQuery object then find an element by ID.

I tried 3 ways bellow, but only the last works. I don't know why the others not works?

```
var html = "<html><body><div id='main'></div></body></html>";

// Not work, return 0
console.log($(html).find('#main').length); 
// Not work, return 0
console.log($($.parseHTML(html)).find('#main').length); 
// Works, return 1
console.log($("<html/>").html(html).find('#main').length);
```

Here is the sample:
http://jsfiddle.net/nbyofkam/2/

Comment: `$(html) == <div id="main"></div>` that's why you can't use `.find()` to find it.

Comment: You can also treat the string as an XML `console.log($($.parseXML(html)).find('#main').length)` but its better to avoid unnecessary wrapping.

Comment: I'm puzzled... seems to me that @YuryTarabanko has given the correct answer here. Had a similar problem, und using `parseXML` instead pf `parseHTML` helps.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's [documented](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/) :

> When passing in complex HTML, some browsers may not generate a DOM that exactly replicates the HTML source provided. As mentioned, jQuery uses the browser"s .innerHTML property to parse the passed HTML and insert it into the current document. During this process, some browsers filter out certain elements such as  `<html>`, `<title>`, or  `<head>` elements. As a result, the elements inserted may not be representative of the original string passed.

As a result, `$(html)` is reduced to `"<div id="main"></div>"`. You can verify that by logging `$(html)[0].outerHTML`.

So you can't use `find` without wrapping it, which is what you do.

Comment: As a workaround, there is something like `findAll`. https://github.com/defunkt/jquery-pjax/blob/master/jquery.pjax.js#L620

Answer (score 8):

An alternate way to do this -

```
var myTestDiv = document.createElement('div');
var mystr = '<div id="main"></div>';
myTestDiv.innerHTML = mystr;

console.log(myTestDiv.querySelector('div#main'));
```