# get() jquery got undefined in my case

Tags: javascript, jquery

[image]

```
var data = $.parseHTML(data.responseText);    
console.log(data) // above img is the result of this
var elem = $(data).find('#all-tickets').get(0);
console.log(elem)
```

I got undefiend, I don't know why. I've tried not to parse html use string to search my id, which is all-tickets, it doesn't work too. Any thought?

I also tried `$(data).find('#all-tickets').parent();`, doesn't work :(

Comment: You are not getting undefined. put  console.log(elem.html()) and check.

Comment: @ParthTrivedi tried that, I'm getting undefined

Comment: Check Dombreak points

Comment: @Satpal above is my console.log(data);

Comment: First Append html to Dom then do access element as `'#all-tickets'`

Comment: Try using `var elem = $(data).find('#all-tickets')[0];`. What is the result of executing `console.log($(data).find('#all-tickets'))`?

Comment: @YeldarKurmangaliyev undefined.

Comment: @Jennifer Copy your HTML here.

Comment: This could help - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25281457/the-right-way-parse-html-to-jquery-object.

Comment: @YeldarKurmangaliyev http://pastebin.com/q0vUJHik

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That seems an array and you are trying to parse the `xml` content with `$.parseHTML()`. Instead you have to either try creating a loop or just append the contents in the div and `.find()` the desired element:

```
var wrapper = $('<div/>', {
    html:data.join('')
});

console.log(wrapper.find('#all-tickets')[0]);
```

check the sample demo:

```js
var arr = ['text', '<a href="#">aaa</a>', '<div id="targetDiv">targetDiv</div>'];

var div = $('<div/>', { html: arr.join('')});

$(document.body).append(div.find('#targetDiv')[0]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: can I don't parse it? I don't understand ur code.. I just want to get the html block #all-tickets

Comment: See the outcome is an `array` not `xml/html/xhtml` and array has indexes so you can't use `.find()` on them.

Comment: @Jennifer check the snippet if this helps.

Comment: do u have any idea why it's an array?